# Flutter TextField hintText align

Tags: flutter, textfield

How does one align `hintText` to the top in a `TextField`?

```
TextField (
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'align me to the top',
    ),
),
```

1. `textAlign` is not affecting `hintText` at all.
2. `TextStyle` does not have `Align` property as `hintStyle` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to update with an image of what you want if this doesn't do it, but I think that it might be as simple as using `labelText` rather than `hintText`.

This is the position of the the various text you can add:

[image: Label, hint, and helper for InputDecoration]

This is what label looks like when there's no hint, the input isn't selected, and there's no text:

[image: Label not selected]

And this is what Label looks like when there's text or it's selected.

[image: Label text example]

Answer (score 1):

Use textAlign property:

```
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField (
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'align me to the top',
    ),
),
```